# Catching default exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I was just wondering if a system exception like say divide by zero actually "throws" something to the application. Would it be possible to catch this somehow by default?.

i mean we can define a custom divide fn which checks for null divisor and throws an exception, but just thought it would be nice if this exception was thrown by default

```
//say I do this
int i;
try
{
i /= 0; // My compiler (gcc) did warn abt the divide by zero :-)
}
catch (...)
{
// Can we get here  for this case?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is OS-dependent. You can do it in Visual C++ code on Windows - catch(...) will also catch so-called structured exceptions that include divisions by zero, access violations, etc., but not in gcc-compiled code on Linux.

Comment: The key observation here is that dividing by 0 is undefined behaviour as far as the C++ standard is concerned. This means individual implementations can do what they like - interrupt the process with a signal, throw an exception, phone your boss and tell him you can't code for toffee, whatever.

Comment: For Windows you could use SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to install an handler which in turn could throw C++ exceptions, e.g. derived from std::exception.

Comment: You need to turn on /EHa to catch divide by zero, etc in Visual C++:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys.. I didn't know the fact that this one was undefined in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard does not say that divide by zero throws an exception - it says that it is undefined behaviour.

Also, when you say:

```
i /= 0; // My compiler (gcc) did warn abt the divide by zero :-)
```

the compiler can only give the warning if the thing you divide by is a constant.